# Windows Server 2008 PPTP connection disconnects at random times and will not reconnect

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, pptp

I'm running into an issue with a VPN over a PPTP (WAN Miniport) connection. There are two significant issues:

1. The connection will not stay active if we log off the machine. Currently we login via terminal server, connect the VPN and disconnect the session so it stays active in the background. This is not a desirable solution.
2. Even if we just disconnect the terminal session, at random times the VPN disconnects itself and does not automatically reconnect even though the properties are setup to have it reconnect automatically.

How do I go about debugging/fixing this issue? Google searches have turned up nothing of significance. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just configure RRAS on the server to demand-dial the VPN connection?

Comment: I'm now wholly familiar with RRAS but I'll look for a tutorial. Do you have any favorite sites that might have more informatioN?